# How to solve the following err?

Tags: android, eclipse

I m trying to run my test application for Andriod first time.I m getting that errors
**Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Android 3.1': Aborting launch.**

Comment: do you have an avd with version 3.1 or above installed?

Comment: Did you configed your Android Virtual Device?

Comment: yes,i did.I installed avd version 4.0.

Comment: great..solved it because I checked Avd config.Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6161805/1218762