# Can't run Android app in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have downloaded the SDK and Eclipse, everything...
Once I try to click Run, on the application "Hello World!", it shows this:

```
[2014-05-22 14:43:21 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\application\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-05-22 14:43:21 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\application\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-05-22 15:17:57 - TechSamay] ------------------------------
[2014-05-22 15:17:57 - TechSamay] Android Launch!
[2014-05-22 15:17:57 - TechSamay] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-22 15:17:57 - TechSamay] Performing com.example.techsamay.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-22 15:17:57 - TechSamay] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.4.2'.
[2014-05-22 15:17:58 - TechSamay] Performing com.example.techsamay.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-22 15:18:00 - TechSamay] Launch canceled!
[2014-05-22 15:18:11 - TechSamay] ------------------------------
[2014-05-22 15:18:11 - TechSamay] Android Launch!
[2014-05-22 15:18:11 - TechSamay] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-22 15:18:11 - TechSamay] Performing com.example.techsamay.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-22 15:18:11 - TechSamay] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.4.2'.
[2014-05-22 15:18:13 - TechSamay] Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Android 4.4.2': Aborting launch.
[2014-05-22 15:18:13 - TechSamay] Performing com.example.techsamay.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-22 15:18:14 - TechSamay] Launch canceled!
```

Why?, don't know how to fix it, Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161418/android-failed-to-find-an-avd-compatible-with-target-android-1-6-error

Comment: Make sure you created the correct AVD (Android virtual device) with the correct API (in your case 4.4.2).

Comment: Thanks, but how?. I am new in this...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have at least one emulator (also known as AVD or Android Virtual Device) it's because Eclipse can't find an emulator compatible with the minimum Android version of your app.

I'd recommend to set the minimum required Android lower for your app unless it's strictly necessary, that way it will also be available to many more devices when you launch it.

In [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) you will find more info about it, but basically all you need to do is 
to set the attribute `android:minSdkVersion` in your `androidManifest.xml` to a lower number.

Take a look at the [Android API Levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) to get an idea of which one to pick. I'd say a 9 is very safe and should be in line with your app's goal in terms of compatibility. I'd say go higher only if you have a reason that justifies it.

An example of the line that you need to change in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```